# Web console supporting the SSH Command

Tags: php

I am trying to implement a web console  using the PHPterm . By the PHPterm  most of the commands can run in the console.But can't login to a server by using the SSH command.

It will display an error that host key verification failed.Is there any other web console supporting the SSH command using PHP and ajax.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can imagine, PHPterm is e mere **Unix shell emulator**. It just gives you the possibility to execute shell commands from the browser, providing you the look and feel of a normal shell.

If you're receiving a "host key verification failed" error, I guess the problem resides in the SSH connection rather than in PHPterm itself.

Did you try to perform the SSH connection without using PHP term, but a simple terminal?

Is your public in the right place?

Is your public key contained in the authorized key?

The [verbose mode for SSH](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch07_03.htm) could help you in identifying the reason of the problem.